# Symfony 6 validator not working for phone number

Tags: symfony, validation, symfony-forms

So I have some problems with phone number validation.

The error I have:
[image]

This happens, when I try to put something what is not a number. I need to prevent this.

I have already tried many ways, but in some reason nothing work. Can you tell me where is my mistake?

What am I tried before in model(Entity):

```
 #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
   1) // #[Assert\Regex('/^\(0\)[0-9]*$')]
or 2) // #[Assert\Type(
    //     type: 'integer',
    //     message: 'The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}.',
    // )]
    private ?int $phone = null;
```

Also I tried this in my Form:

```
->add('phone', TelType::class,[
        'required' => false,
        'constraints' => [
            new Regex([
                'pattern' => '/^\+?[0-9]{10,14}$/',
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid phone number',
            ])
        ],
        ])
```

Validator is imported, regex also, for name and email validation work fine. Problem only with the phone number.

What wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: form inputs are strings. You are asserting it is an integer, which it is not. Try `numeric` instead of `integer`

Comment: As craigh said you cannot store a phone number as an integer, `0960` is not a valid integer and would be stored as `960` which obviously is not what you want. Why not use a string instead since your validation should handle phone numbers (and you also store the `+` char if typed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your typehinting on your `$phone` property that's causing the error, just like [@craigh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2600812/craigh) and [@Dylan KAS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11350193/dylan-kas) mention. `TelType` returns a `string`, as it's an input element of type `tel`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel).

By typehinting `?int`, PHP expects the provided value to either be null or an integer. Assuming you are trying invalid phonenumbers like 'abcd' or '124578785758583', Symfony will throw an error as that those are strings.

I'd recommend to replace your typehinting with `?string` and make sure your regex is correct and you check for type "numeric", which uses the [is_numeric](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function:

```
#[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
#[Assert\Regex('/^\(0\)[0-9]*$')]
#[Assert\Type(
    type: 'numeric',
    message: 'The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}.',
)]
private ?string $phone = null;
```